# RPC call doesnt working. GUICE + DISPATCH

Tags: java, gwt, guice, rpc, gwt-dispatch

I have a simple action and result classes. Handler for this just increment variable in action and returns it in result.
**Action**

```
public class IncrementCounter implements Action<IncrementCounterResult> {
    private int amount;

    /** For serialization only. */
    public IncrementCounter(){}

    public IncrementCounter(int amount){
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
public class IncrementCounterResult implements Result {
    private int amount;
    private int current;

    /** For serialization only. */
    public IncrementCounterResult(){}

    public IncrementCounterResult(int amount, int current){
        this.amount = amount;
        this.current = current;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public int getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }
}
```

I have an action module, where i bind action on handler.
**ActionsModule**

```
public class ActionsModule extends ActionHandlerModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureHandlers() {
        bindHandler(IncrementCounter.class, IncrementCounterHandler.class);
    }
}
```

**DispatchServletModule**

```
public class DispatcherServletModule extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        serve("/dispatch").with(GuiceStandardDispatchServlet.class);
    }
}
```

**Handler**, which increment field in action and returns it in result.

```
public class IncrementCounterHandler implements ActionHandler<IncrementCounter, IncrementCounterResult> {
    private int current = 0;


    public Class<IncrementCounter> getActionType() {
        return IncrementCounter.class;
    }


    public IncrementCounterResult execute(IncrementCounter action, ExecutionContext context) throws ActionException {
        current += action.getAmount();
        return new IncrementCounterResult(action.getAmount(), current);
    }


    public void rollback(IncrementCounter action, IncrementCounterResult result, ExecutionContext context) throws ActionException {
        current = result.getCurrent() - result.getAmount();
    }
}
```

And the last one is **listener**:

```
public class RpcCommandGuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new ServerDispatchModule(), new ActionsModule());
    }
}
```

Here is my **web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>server.RpcCommandGuiceConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Module.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I call dispatch.execute when button clicked. and code jumps in onFailure section.
I have this in log :

```
WARN] 404 - POST /Module/dispatch (127.0.0.1) 1380 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      X-GWT-Permutation: HostedMode
      X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/Module/
      Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
      Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/Module/Module.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
      Content-Length: 238
      Connection: keep-alive
      Pragma: no-cache
      Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Can anybody help to resolve this problem ?

...
Here gwt file

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.0//EN"
        "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/2.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <source path="client"/>
    <source path="shared"/>
    <source path="server"/>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <inherits name="com.mvp4g.Mvp4gModule"/>
    <inherits name="org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.Highcharts"/>
    <inherits name="net.customware.gwt.dispatch.Dispatch" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject" />
    <entry-point class='client.Module'/>
</module>
```

Comment: i think i have a problem with xml.file. Maybe i mess <servlet> tags. But when i am adding in to <servlet-class> server.DispatcherServletModule i have an error: this class is not assigneble to 'javax.servlet.Servelt', but he extends import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;? how does he know smth about this javax.servlet ?

Comment: <servlet-class>server.DispatcherServletModule</servlet-class> here is error is not assigneble to 'javax.servlet.Servlet',

Comment: can anybody help ? i am still cant resolve this (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to prefix the `serve` in `DispatcherServletModule` with the module name. In your case it looks like it's in the root, so it's only the module name: `Module`:

> serve("/Module/dispatch").with(GuiceStandardDispatchServlet.class);

Comment: you just saved my life) thank you very  much. i spent all day and didn't resolve this, and in the morning today you helped me. thx